# Spoof MAC address on Android programmatically

Tags: java, android

I made a small app that allow you to spoof mac address of an android device. The commands 
"ip link set wlan0 down", "ip link set wlan0 address
NE:WM:AC" , "ip link set wlan0 up", "ip link" works perfectly in an android terminal emulator, but the second not work in the app :(
In fact the MAC does not change

```
String[] commands = { "ip link set wlan0 down" , "ip link set wlan0 address NE:WM:AC" , "ip link set wlan0 up", "ip link" }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super .onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   addListenerOnButton();
}
public void addListenerOnButton() {
   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
         try {
            RunAsRoot(commands);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   });
}
public void RunAsRoot(String[] cmds) throws IOException{
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su" );
   DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
   for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
      os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+ " \n " );
   }
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   String line = null;
   while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      Log.i(line,line);
   }
   os.writeBytes( "exit \n " );
   os.flush();
}
```